# How to monetarize Flutter websites / get Adsense approval?

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-web, adsense

It is known that it's possible to use Adsense ads.

Unfortunately i can't get approval cause of "no publisher content". This is apparently what happens to anybody who tries to get approval for a Flutter web app. It makes sense cause Adsense is for text based websites.

Are there any alternatives? Is there something I can do to get approval anyway?
[image]